# react-day-picker setState delayed to display on console

Tags: reactjs, react-day-picker

After the first date selection the selected date is not displayed on console and delayed and only set on state on the next selection.

This is the link to my code.
[go to sample code](https://codesandbox.io/s/rl871xpnln)

Am i missing something? I expect it to display on console on the first selection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`setState` is *asynchronous.***

If you call `setState` and immediately use `this.state`, chances are it will not be updated yet.

If you want to set the state and immediately act on that change, you can pass in a callback function.

So, in your case his code will work:

```
handleFromChange(from) {
    this.setState({ from }, () => console.log(this.state));
}
```

Docs:

> `setState()` does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing `this.state` after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value. There is no
>   guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to `setState` and calls may
>   be batched for performance gains.